# Как вставить запись с полями связи many-to-one?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

у меня есть модель

```
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { Order } from './order.entity';
import { People } from '../../people/entities/people.entity';

@Entity('order_people')
export class OrderPeople {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Order)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'order_id',
  })
  order: Order;

  @ManyToOne(() => People)
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'people_id'
  })
  people: People;

  @Column({
    type: 'decimal',
    precision: 15,
    scale: 4
  })
  price: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'int'
  })
  quantity: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'decimal',
    precision: 15,
    scale: 4
  })
  cost: number;
}
```

пытаюсь вставить данные

```
[
  { peopleId: 1, orderId: 1, price: 122.4533, quantity: 2 },
  { peopleId: 2, orderId: 1, price: 244.4433, quantity: 2 }
]
```

Я вставляю данные через queryBuilder вот так

```
await this.orderPeopleRepository.createQueryBuilder('insert')
.insert().
values(updatePeopleDto)
.execute()
```

Записи вставляются в базу данных, но поля peopleId и orderId пусты. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://typeorm.io/relational-query-builder

Comment: вместо `peopleId`, необходима связанная сущность, в вашем случае People